# Metodo Post Angular

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, angular

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando como BackEnd ASP.NET C#, e com front Angular5! Estou fazendo um método post pela primeira vez e não está fluindo bem!

No BackEnd eu tenho um método da seguinte forma:

```html
[HttpPost, Route("api/usuario/novo")]
public void Post([FromBody]Usuario usuario)
{
    _usuarioService.Adicionar(usuario);
}
```

Ou seja, é um método Post, que vai receber um usuário e vai add o mesmo...

No Angular eu tenho a seguinte requisição

```js
inserindoUsuario(usuarios: any){
this.usuariosModel = {
     UsuarioId: null,
     Nome: usuarios.nome,
     Sobrenome: usuarios.sobrenome,
     Email: usuarios.email,
     Senha: usuarios.senha,
     Corretor: usuarios.corretor,
     Contrato: usuarios.contrato
 }

 let headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 this.Http.post('http://localhost:57301/api/usuario/novo', JSON.stringify(this.usuariosModel), { headers: headers })
 .subscribe(() => {
     console.log(this.usuariosModel);
 });
}
```

Ou seja, crio um usuário, monto o Header da requisição e chamo o Subscribe... Porem no console do navegador apresenta o seguinte erro:

```html
Failed to load http://localhost:57301/api/usuario/novo: Response to
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The
response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Porém meu Header já está configurado..

Comment: Da uma pesquisada em como deixar cors no seu backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque não está habilitado requisições da origem `http://localhost:4200`.

> Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Para permitir requisições, tanto de origens especificas, como de qualquer uma é necessário habilitar o `cors`.

no `nuget` procure por `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` ou pelo `Package Manager Console` execute o comando

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Após isso, em sua classe `WebApiConfig` adicione o seguinte código.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Com o `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));` são liberados, no primeiro parâmetro todas **origens**, no segundo todos **headers** e no terceiro, todos o **verbos**.

Você poder ler mais sobre `Cors` na [Documentação da microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

**Porque ocorreu esse erro:**

Por segurança o navegador impede que uma página web faça chamadas AJAX para outro domínio.

Nesse caso, sua aplicação Angular roda em um domínio diferente de sua aplicação backend.

**Como resolver o problema:**

Habilitando `Cross Origin Resource Sharing` (**CORS**) você conseguirá fazer essa chamada.

Já implementei CORS para uma aplicação [Asp.Net CORE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1), mas pesquisando para o caso de uma aplicação Asp.Net MVC (créditos: [fonte em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method)):

Crie um novo atributo:

```
public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Adicione o atributo na sua action:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
[HttpPost, Route("api/usuario/novo")]
public void Post([FromBody]Usuario usuario)
{
    _usuarioService.Adicionar(usuario);
}
```

No link de referência você vai exemplos para habilitar CORS em aplicações Asp.Net MVC e Asp.Net APIs. Lembrando que você tem a opção de resolver via pacote **[Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Cors/)** também (conforme resposta do @Barbetta).